# MulterError: Unexpected field, when posting a file

Tags: node.js, http, multipartform-data, multer

I have the following test code

```
var express = require('express');
const res = require('express/lib/response');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var multer = require('multer');
var campos = multer();
var conf = require('../config/config');
var router = express.Router();
 

router.post('/', campos.single('foto_1'), async(req, res, next) => {
  
   res.send("teste")


});

module.exports = router;
```

Now my postman test.

[image: postman]

I was getting the error when performing the request using Angular, I isolated the error down to postman and turned out that the error was not related to Angular.

Comment: sorry, I think I should have posted more code. I took app.use(express.json()) that was somewhere else I know I am getting "teste" to display when I access the route.

Comment: most likely it's not related to multer either, but postman. try uploading it with curl

Answer (score 0):

I am learning Node.js I barely touched middlewares... the issue is that I had app.use(express.json). Maybe this was comflicting with multer. Now I can get one file campos.single("") and several campos.array("files").